# Getting the error while working on third party xercesc library the prebuild is getting failed at the dependant library xalanc lib at aix platform

Tags: c++11

../../../../obj/SAX2Handler.o -o ../../../../bin/MsgCreator -L/BR4/ism_7.4.0.2/Devarapalli.Lavanya_p02724/mtpt1/TOP/aix/thirdparty/xalanc/xalan-c-1.11/xercesc/lib -lxerces-c
../../../bin/MsgCreator /BR4/ism_7.4.0.2/Devarapalli.Lavanya_p02724/mtpt1/TOP/aix/thirdparty/xalanc/xalan-c-1.11/c/src/xalanc/NLS/en_US/XalanMsg_en_US.xlf -TYPE inmem -LOCALE en_US
gmake[4]: *** [../../../nls/include/LocalMsgData.hpp] IOT/Abort trap (core dumped)
gmake[3]: *** [locale] Error 2
gmake[2]: *** [all] Error 2
gmake[1]: *** [/BR4/ism_7.4.0.2/Devarapalli.Lavanya_p02724/mtpt1/TOP/aix/thirdparty/xalanc/xalan-c-1.11/c/lib/libxalan-c.a] Error 2
gmake: *** [createsdk] Error 1

I tried to make some code changes in the make file but it didn't work.

Comment: This could be related to https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=98390 . It would be great if you can extract the exact command that is failing from the output that you get from 'make' and then edit the question with just that command.

Comment: gmake[4]: *** [../../../nls/include/LocalMsgData.hpp] IOT/Abort trap (core dumped) this where it is failing exactly. I tried to to resolve this I didn't get any clue because I can't find the LocalMsgData.hpp in my source code at all. please help me in this. Thank you!!